# Python problema y duda con la función all()

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculo

```
print(all(2 % j != 0 for j in range(2, 1)))
print(all(2 % j != 0 for j in range(2, 2)))
```

No entiendo por qué estas dos líneas dan True. Probé distintas veces a hacer ranges en dónde n1 era mayor o igual a n2 `range(n1>=n2)` y si lo metía en un bucle:

```
for i in range(2,2):
    print(i)
for i in range(2,1):
    print(i)
```

Directamente no retorna nada, ni siquiera da None o una excepción.

Entonces en `all(2 % j != 0 for j in range(2, 1))` para la primera sección: `2 % j != 0` cómo es que se ejecuta si `j` directamente no tiene valor ya que el bucle for no da valor alguno? y cómo es que si `j` no tiene valor (según mi criterio) y no se ejecuta el calculo, aún así devuelve True?

Perdón si no me expliqué bien. Tengan en cuenta por favor que soy nuevo en la programación, recién estoy aprendiendo, gracias por cualquier ayuda <3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido!

Lo que estas haciendo es correcto. La funcion range(2,2) y range(2,1) devuelven un rango vacio. Vas a ver que si haces `list(range(2,2))` por ejemplo te va a dar `[]`.
Al darte un rango vacio la funcion `all` no tiene nada que evaluar.
Es como si dijeses "todo lo que esta en este rango es no divisible por dos?" y logicamente esto es cierto por que no tenes nada en la coleccion (si queres ser un poco mas estricto con la logica, esto es como cuando negas el antecedente, la implicacion es verdadera)
Por lo tanto la funcion `all([])` devuelve siempre True.

Comment: Gracias! ahora entiendo mucho mejor todo :D.